# Send SMS Message by php using array

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I have account on sms gateway and I want to send sms message using php language 
the information which I found in User Guide like this 
to send sms message I  cane use this code  and I can send message using it

```
 $xmlString='data=<BILGI>
 <KULLANICI_ADI>username</KULLANICI_ADI>
   <SIFRE>password</SIFRE>
  <BASLIK>subject</BASLIK> 
 </BILGI>
 <ISLEM>
 <YOLLA>
   <MESAJ>hello from NetCom   </MESAJ>
 <NO>xxxxxxxxx phone number</NO>
     </YOLLA>

  </ISLEM>';  

  //API URL
    $postUrl='http://www.toplusmsnet.com/services/api.php?islem=sms';

    $Veriler =  $xmlString;
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Veriler);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
```

I can send sms message using above code but I want to pass message's attribute using array like this

```
       $destination = array("messageId" => $messageId, 
        "to" => $to);
       $message = array("from" => $from,
      "destinations" => array($destination),
       "text" => $text,
       "notifyUrl" => $notifyUrl,
      "notifyContentType" => $notifyContentType,
       "callbackData" => $callbackData);
```

to make sms configuration more easy. how can I make information  to be in array and send it using curl 
I wish I explained my problem correctly

Comment: You can start of by not using `array()` and use `[]` to make your life easier if you are on 5.4 or above. It makes your code more readable.

Comment: Try another approach: use placeholders inside the XML like `%destination_number%` and just substitute them in the string when you have the data in your `$destination` and `$message` arrays, before even thinking about curl

Comment: as you know there are many  and many sms gateway provider and my system will allow user to config sms by using the sms which he has account on it, user can configure it if his sms provider like clickatell give him http request but this provider give him an xml file

Comment: can you make an array from the above xml file ?